# change table background inside <td>

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, razor, html-table, background-color

is it possible to edit table's class (background-color) inside the td if ..else condition.

```
 @<table class='widgetContentText'>
       <tr>
            <th>..</th>
            <th></th>
            <th>..</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
    @If (item.QueueLength(medium) > threshold.Queuethreshold1(medium)) Then
        @If (item.QueueLength(medium) > threshold.Queuethreshold2(medium)) Then
            @<td class='effect' style="background-color:#FF3333" align="center">
                @item.QueueLength(medium)
            </td>
                Else
            @<td class='effect' style="background-color:#FFA500" align="center">
                @item.QueueLength(medium)
            </td>
                End If
            Else
        @<td align="center">
            @item.QueueLength(medium)
        </td>
            End If
```

Comment: why this does not look plain html5 to me. am i missing something ?

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: ASP.Net Razor -vb code

Comment: What error are you getting? It is possible... you can do it through Razor or you could keep the html tidy and then use javascript to change the css class.

Comment: It would properly be better for you to make a property on your ViewModel and then calculate the proper color in your controller, so you don't have to do too much logic in your view code. Then you can just use that property in your view easily